# How to paste text in VIM

Tags: vim, neovim

I started to learn how to use VIM a few days ago(i'm using NeoVim), now i need to paste some code from internet to my file. I'm trying to press 'P', but it doesn't work for me. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: try `"+P` to past from the system clipboard

Answer (score 3):

If you are in insert mode just hit:

```
Ctrl-r +
```

If the code on the clipboard has indentation:

```
Ctrl-r Ctrl-o +
```

Answer (score 0):

In Normal Mode enter `:help clipboard` and read that and anything related.

In Normal mode enter quotation mark, plus, p  `"+p"` to copy the contents of the plus register in to your buffer.

Watch this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_rbfQqrm7g